# Mount encrypted .dmg from terminal using list of possible passwords?

Tags: macos, encryption, terminal

I have an external drive with an encrypted disk image that I've forgotten the password to-- but I know it's a combination of 4-5 passwords I was using at the time it was encrypted. I generated a list of all the combinations I think it could be (with character variations I use, such as @ for 'a'), and I'd like to automate trying each of them as there are several hundred guesses.

I'm using '''echo -n 'Password' | hdiutil attach -stdinpass /path/Disk.dmg''' to try to mount the disk from terminal on Mac, and I know this works using a test disk image I made.

So, is there a way I can pass the list of password guesses to terminal instead of having to paste them in? I've considered using Automator on Mac but it won't take my code above in the "do shell script" command.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
cat yourfile.txt | while read line; do hdiutil attach -stdinpass /path/DMG.dmg; done
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful